# Form validation with Bootstrap and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to unite the AngularJS validation model with the Bootstrap form validation display.

- If a user loads an empty form, I don't want the form to display error message right away. I want to wait until the user interacts with the form.
- If a user submit the form with required fields not filled out, I also want to display an error message.
- If a user starts typing in the field, I want error messages to show up right away.

So I have to check `myForm.$submitted`, `myForm.<fieldName>.$dirty` as well as `myForm.<fieldName>.$touched`.

However, it makes a lot of duplicated code with very few variation.

I've tried to make a directive to fix this issue but I can't seem to find the right way to wrap this complexity away.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group required" ng-class="{ 'has-error': myForm.firstname.$invalid && (myForm.firstname.$dirty || myForm.$submitted || myForm.firstname.$touched)  }">
    <label for="firstname" class="control-label" translate>Profile.FirstName</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" required ng-model="vm.profile.firstName"/>
    <p class="help-block" ng-if="myForm.firstname.$error.required" translate>Forms.Default.Required</p>
</div>
```

I want to take the whole `ng-class` attribute and replace it by something more succinct. The directive seemed like the way to go so tried this:

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app')
    .directive('hasError', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                form: '=bsForm',
                control: '=bsControl'
            },
            link: function(scope, element){
                scope.$watch('form', function(){
                    var isInvalid = scope.control.$invalid && scope.control.$dirty;
                    element.toggleClass('has-error', isInvalid);
                });

            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

**Usage:**

```
<div class="form-group required" has-error bs-form="myForm" bs-control="myForm.firstname">
...
</div>
```

This however was not refreshing when properties of `form` changed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

So... I managed to make a directive work properly for exactly my usage.

If there is a better way, please prove me wrong.

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app')
    .directive('hasError', [function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                form: '=bsForm',
                control: '=bsControl'
            },
            link: function(scope, element){
                scope.$watchGroup(['control.$invalid', 'control.$dirty', 'control.$touched', 'form.$submitted'], function(){
                    var isInvalid = scope.control.$invalid && (scope.control.$dirty || scope.form.$submitted || scope.control.$touched);
                    element.toggleClass('has-error', isInvalid);
                });

            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this one. My solution took a slightly different approach, but it may be helpful here (you can view the gist on [Github](https://gist.github.com/trevorhreed/9b285f39b1d2e93d87c3#file-form-validator-js)).

Essentially, what I do is wrap all my form data inside a single object and I assign that object to a `<form>` attribute. I then watch that object and any time it changes, I select all elements with the `ng-dirty` and `ng-invalid` classes (this selector could be changed to whatever you like). I then loop through each of these elements and update messages for each of them.

Here's the code:

```
(function() {
  "use strict"
  angular.module('app')
    .directive('formValidator', function() {
      return {
        require: '^form',
        scope: {
          formData: '=',
          validateAll: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
          window.frm = ctrls;
          var selector = '.ng-dirty.ng-invalid';

          function validate() {
            $(".formValidator-input-validation-error-message").remove();
            element.find(selector).each(function(index, el) {
              $el = $(el);
              var messages = [];
              var classes = $el.attr('class').match(/[\d\w-_]+/g);
              for (var i in classes) {
                var lastIndex = classes[i].lastIndexOf('-invalid-');
                if (lastIndex != -1) {
                  var validationMessageAttr = "data-" + classes[i].substr(lastIndex + 9) + "-validation-message";
                  var msg = $el.attr(validationMessageAttr);
                  if (!msg) {
                    msg = element.attr(validationMessageAttr);
                    if (!msg) {
                      msg = "Invalid!";
                    }
                  }
                  messages.push("<div class='validator'>" + msg + "</div>");
                }
              }
              $(el).after("<div style='position:absolute;' class='formValidator-input-validation-error-message'>" + messages.join() + "</div>");
            });
          }
          scope.$watch(function() {
            return scope.formData;
          }, function() {
            validate();
          }, true);
          scope.$watch('validateAll', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            selector = !!newValue ? '.ng-invalid' : '.ng-dirty.ng-invalid';
            validate();
          });
        }
      };
    })
})();
```